# How to see full manual for commands in terminal for Mac OS?

Tags: macos

I am completely new to Mac OS and I am trying to figure out how to display in terminal all flags for `echo` command. When I do  `man echo` it only shows me one flag which is `-n` and I am pretty sure there are many more.
I've googled it but found nothing.

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shell builtins such as `echo`, the man page does not offer an accurate description, since it describes the *binary* (usually found in `/bin`), not the builtin.

For help on the built-in commands in Bash, use

```sh
help echo
```

For instance, on my version of macOS this shows me:

> ```
> echo: echo [-neE] [arg ...]
>     Write arguments to the standard output.
>
>     Display the ARGs, separated by a single space character and followed by a
>     newline, on the standard output.
>
>     Options:
>       -n  do not append a newline
>       -e  enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
>       -E  explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes
> …
> ```

In zsh, the closest equivalent is `man zshbuiltins`, which shows the documentation for *all* built-in commands. To find a given command in it, type `/    echo` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>. Note that there are multiple spaces between `/` and `echo`! This isn’t necessary, but it often filters out false hits.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for such quick response. I've tried ``` help echo```
but it says  ``` zsh: command not found: help```

Comment: @VladVlad Ah, you’re using zsh, not Bash. I keep forgetting that this is the default on new versions of macOS. I don’t know the zsh equivalent — zsh usually uses man pages for its builtins, but you’re right that `man echo` does *not* document all supported flags (e.g. `-E` is missing).

Comment: oh ok ( Is there any way I can change zsh to bash somehow?

Comment: @VladVlad If you type `bash`, you will start Bash. If you want to set Bash as your default shell, you can do so via `chsh`. However, *I do not recommend this!* zsh is actually a much better shell than Bash, and unless you’re already proficient at using Bash there’s no reason to prefer it to the more modern zsh.

Comment: @VladVlad Please have a look at the update at the bottom of my answer. You *can* find the same information for zsh, after all.

Answer (score 1):

echo is a function of your shell and it behaves differently if you have a different shell. zsh or more 'advanced' shells may support extra args, but i've for one not heard about other args to echo than -n (which removes the trailing newlines).

macos is closer to freebsd than linux and it comes bundles with bash (Bourne again Shell), but in normal scenarios you should only assume that sh or ash (in Alpine) is available. E.g. while you may be able to use extra flags for echo with a different shell, you shouldn't expect that shell to be available or default on a target system.

I think a better way to find out what you want is to google what you want echo to do and likely there'll be lots of ways described how to do that outside echo (printf, cat, tee or similar).